# I want to show records from one table order by other table's primary key and one other columns

Tags: php, mysql

From single table i am getting desired result but i want to show them by the order of other table's primary key column
I get multiple records when i try to join them or select multiple tables
I tried and learnt main queries but not understanding how do i form  a logic

```
SELECT req_id 
FROM requests 
     INNER join messages 
where (sender_id=1 or reciever_id=1) AND req_token=1 
ORDER by messages.message_id ASC
```

Comment: I have to assume, that you don't understand how joins in general or inner joins in particular work. please look those up, because I'm fairly certain, your inner join is lacking an ON clause.

Comment: An inner join without an on clause is syntactically ok but is the same as a cross join. If that's what you want fine but you should really use cross join syntax.

Comment: @P.Salmon can you guide me how can i show multiple instances as a one result ?

Comment: Sure, if you can add sample data and expected output as text to the question (or sqlfiddle) I'd be happy to.